# Pick random array item from response in Paw

Tags: paw-app

Given the following API response, I'd like to use the "Response Parsed Body" dynamic variable and select a random id from the array:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "2"
  }
]
```

Using `[0].id` gives me `1`, but there's no way to select a random item. This is likely a problem with JSONPath, but it would be nice to have Paw implement a way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a custom dynamic value.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}


function evaluate(context) {
  var request = context.getRequestByName('OtherRequestName')
  var lastExchange = request.getLastExchange()
  var body = JSON.parse(lastExchange.responseBody)
  var list = body // path to list within body
  var i = getRandomInt(0, list.length)
  return list[i].id
}
```

Comment: Ok, that mostly works. Though it relies on the last exchange (execution) of the linked request. Which requires that request to have been executed. And also caches results, which won't work if using this in a `delete` method for example. Though this seems to be a limitation of Paw.

Comment: Also, is there a way to set the title of custom dynamic value? Right now it's just stuck at "Custom". Creating a `title` function seems to have no effect, despite the docs.

Comment: Finally, for anyone else reading this, custom dynamic values are somewhat hidden, which is why I had no idea this was even possible. Add one with: `right click > Extensions > Custom`

Comment: @JoshuaJabbour  Since we are depending on the response body of the last request yes it must have been run before. If you would like to depend on the sent body/headers/url of another request you can do this without the other request having been sent. 

You can create your own dynamic values (if you do this you will also be able to export UI element) https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Extensions/Create_Dynamic_Values_Extension.

Comment: For quickly adding dynamic values paw has autocomplete, just start with a `{`  so for example to create a custom DV just type `{cu` and select the custom DV from the autocomplete list.

Comment: Ok, I suppose that will work. Though the way I (naively) expected it to work was that the linked request would be executed automatically before the dynamic value is extracted. This seems way more useful, because as it stands now you manually have to go and execute all the other commands you depend on.

Comment: And please add support for `title` and `text` functions inside custom dynamic values.

Comment: @JoshuaJabbour we are working on auto run linked request behavior however since it is common for many request in a file to link to one request (eg login get auth) we do not want the user to fire this child request many time. Therefore it will be more of an opt in, "run with all dependent requests". this is also needed since it is possible the child request makes modifications ( that are not repeatable, delete, post etc)

Comment: @JoshuaJabbour I see the case for `title` and will add this to our backlog, what do you mean by `text`?

Comment: I'm not sure, what does `text` provide for extensions? By my understanding it's the dynamic text description, but I don't really know. I guess what I'd like is for a custom dynamic value to work just like a custom-built extension.

Comment: And awesome that you're working on autorun linked requests. That would solve all the problems I had with this, so yay! And thanks for your input and help here!

Answer (score 0):

```
let list = JSON.parse(responseBody);
let random_num = _.random(list.length);
let randomId= list[random_num].id;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("randomId", randomId);
```